# Communicating self hosted webservice running locally to the web page

Tags: signalr, asp.net-web-api2, self-hosting

I have a http enabled windows service(self hosted) running locally on my machine which  wraps an instrument driver connected to the COM port.The idea is for my web application(which is hosted on the server,which contains several sub applications which doesn't require instrument interactions) to communicate with the local device and issue commands from within the web browser. Implementation is when the web browser opens it calls the web service instance like "http://localhost:80/api/Connect".This works as expected..but i wanted to know what are the issues which i am not foreseeing with this approach or if there is any alternatives to achieve the same in a smarter way. Appreciate any opinion.

Comment: Can you add any additional context..  For example, are you communicating across the internet, or locally on your LAN (i.e. do you need SSL?)  Is there some reason you chose to use a Windows Service instead of hosting it on IIS?  Are there any authentication requirements?  etc.

Comment: Hi Jared, everything is within the same network(internal). this web service(driver for instrument) needs to be installed on every client machine requiring this functionality and I am not intending to configure IIS on every client machine..

Comment: Will you be enabling SSL?

Comment: We have a product similar to what you have proposed. The difference is the selfhosted svc sends data back to the server via browser. This is causing mixed content warnings from browsers. I am looking at SignalR to reroute the event from browser via server to the client. May be this is something that interests you.